# Code reusability in Junit Test cases

Tags: java, junit

```
public abstract class BaseTest {

  protected static HiveTable hiveTable1 = null;
  protected static HiveTable hiveTable2 = null;

  @Test
  public void testHiveMetadata() throws DataConnectorException {
      Assert.assertFalse(hiveTable1.exists());
      hiveTable1.create();
      Assert.assertTrue(hiveTable1.exists());
      putRecords(hiveTable1);
      Assert.assertEquals(3, hiveTable1.getRecordCount());

      Assert.assertFalse(hiveTable2.exists());
      hiveTable2.create();
      Assert.assertTrue(hiveTable2.exists());
      Assert.assertEquals(0, hiveTable2.getRecordCount()); 

      //more code    
  }
}


public class SomeTest1 extends BaseTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws DataConnectorException {

        hiveTable1 = HiveDatasources.getLocalHiveTable1();
        hiveTable2 = HiveDatasources.getLocalHiveTable2();
    }
}
```

Basically, `abstract` class `BaseTest` has core testing logic and other classes like `SomeTest1` are populating objects needed in `abstract` class.

There are `SomeTest2`, `SomeTest3` and some other classes which test with different types of hiveTable objects *(like hive table with different file formats)*.

As per my understanding when I `mvn clean install` my project only test cases of concrete classes will run.

Is this right approach to solve the problem like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise is rather different: consider to be really careful about using inheritance here to avoid code duplication.

You see, the essential point of unit tests is: they should help you to **quickly** identify the root cause of bugs in your production code (listen [here](http://www.se-radio.net/2016/05/se-radio-episode-256-jay-fields-on-working-effectively-with-unit-tests/) for some thoughts around that topic).

This means: the core quality of a unit test is that you get from a fail message to the core of the problem as fast as possible. Any additional layer of abstraction ... slows you down. Meaning: in your setup, when a test fails, you have to understand that

1. Ups, there is actually **no** @Test method in the class you were told about a failing test
2. So you have to figure: ah, it is defined in some base class
3. Then you start reading there ... to figure: "oh, and how are things setup?!
4. To come back to your failing test class

Maybe that isnt a problem for the first two weeks after creating this code. But what happens in 2 years, when new people are on your team; and you are out; and then one of those tests fails?!

My thought here: instead of using inheritance, use composition. Meaning: create a helper class that provides "test helper" methods; and then allow for a bit of code duplication and give **all** your SomeTest classes the fields in order and test methods to do the test work.

And finally the one thing you should **definitely** change: you have multiple asserts in your one test method. Better roll that out and have multiple tests, each one doing at max **one** assert.